# Need to pass object in a python array in bash

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I am trying to get the response code for three sites using the below python code snippet. But wondering how I can parse each object in the array to pass through the for loop within the `curl` call.

```
import os

servers = ["google", "yahoo", "nonexistingsite"]
for i in range(len(servers)):
    print(os.system('curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" --silent --output'
                    ' /dev/null "https://servers[i].com"'))
```

With the above code, it's not getting passed through `servers[i]`.

Comment: Don't use `os.system` to run `curl`; use something like the `requests` library to make HTTP requests from within the Python program.

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform *string formatting*, like:

```
import os

servers = ["google", "yahoo", "nonexistingsite"]
for server in servers:
  print(os.system('curl --write-out "%{{http_code}}\\n" --silent --output /dev/null "https://{}.wellsfargo.com"'.format(server)))
```

The above can however still go wrong, if for example the servers contain quotes, etc.

It might be better to here use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and pass it a list of parameters, like:

```
servers = ["google", "yahoo", "nonexistingsite"]
for server in servers:
    p = subprocess.run(
        [
            'curl'
            '--write-out',
            '%{http_code}\\n',
            '--silent',
            '--output'
            '/dev/null',
            'https://{}.wellsfargo.com'.format(server)
        ],
        shell=True,
        capture_output=True
    )
```

Comment: Mine is Python 2.7.10 and i believe subprocess.run module works for 3.5 and later. So i tried your first option, even though it worked - there are two output for each server in the loop. One is the actual 200 OK or a 404 result expected and the additional one is 0 or 1536. Not sure where it comes from.

    `import os

    servers = ["google", "yahoo", "non-existsite"]

    for server in servers:
       print(os.system('curl --write-out "%{{http_code}}\n" --silent --output /dev/null "https://www.{}.com"'.format(server)))`

Comment: @martineau: thanks. I think with escaping it, it might be solved.

Comment: @Gladiator: well If I run this locally, I got this error as well, since it can not resolve the host `yahoo.wellsfargo.com`. Are you sure that domain name exists?

Comment: Gladiator: `subprocess.run()` should work fine in Python 2.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that is correct, yahoo.wellsfargo.com doesn't exist. I corrected it on the last comment. The edited code is as below;
`import os servers = ["google", "yahoo", "non-existsite"] for server in servers: print(os.system('curl --write-out "%{{http_code}}\n" --silent --output /dev/null "https://www.{}.com"'.format(server)))`

This gives two response codes for each server in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Python's string formatting, something like:

`"This string uses an %s" %(argument)` would become "This string uses an argument"

Something like this:

```
print(os.system('curl --write-out "%%{http_code}\n" --silent --output /dev/null "https://%s.wellsfargo.com"') % (servers[i])
```

More here: https://powerfulpython.com/blog/python-string-formatting/

Comment: I think you need to escape the `"%{http_code}\n"` part here, since otherwise it looks for a `http_code` parameter in the formatting call.

Comment: Good call, %% escapes it

Comment: I think you need to escape the backslash in `\n`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `requests` library instead of shelling out to run `curl`:

```
for s in servers:
    resp = requests.get(s)
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Since you don't care about the body of the response, only whether it responds, you could save bandwidth by using the `head` function instead of `get` to retrieve only the headers from the server.